# How to Use TFS in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

I want to use TFS in Android Studio. I installed Visual Studio Team Services and then in TFVC of Settings, i should to select TF executable file, i downloaded TFE of below link but when i Test TF exe file, i give below error.

`The specified path does not lead to a valid TF executable.`

Downloaded link:

https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of [Team Services Plugin for Android Studio](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/AndroidStudioPlugin/Index)?

Comment: Hi Fahim, any update on this question?

Answer (score 3):

Please double check if you have follow below steps:

> You must have the [TF command line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) installed to be able to
>   use TFVC features. The minimum version supported by the plugin is
>   14.0.3. To install the tool, download the latest "TEE-CLC-14.*.*.zip" file and extract it to a known location. After extracting the files,
>   you must **accept the license agreement**. To do so, open a Command
>   Prompt/Terminal window, navigate to the extracted directory, and run
>   `tf eula`. After reading the EULA, enter y `enter code here`to accept
>   it. **NOTE:** If you forget to do this, the plugin may fail to load
>   with a RuntimeException.

For the tool to be detected by the plugin, you must set the location of the executable in the `Settings/Preferences` menu by following these instructions:

1. Go to RD Settings  Version Control -TFVC
2. In the **Path to tf executable** text field, navigate to the location of
       the tf executable.
3. Click **Test** to test that the executable has been found and is working
   as expected.
4. Click **Apply** then **OK** to save and exit.

More details please refer this [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a couple of things to make this work.

I was following this video and it selects 'tf' as executable. I'm using Windows so I had to select tf.cmd as executable. [Getting Started with TFVC inside of Android Studio with the Team Services Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8)

Also I had _JAVA_OPTIONS set in environment variables so when Android Studio was testing tf executable, the first response was:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx2048m

After I removed _JAVA_OPTIONS from environment variables tf executable was accepted.

Going through debuglog Android Studios debuglog was pretty useful to understand the issue:
[How do I collect logs to help troubleshoot an issue?](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/androidstudio#_frequently-asked-questions-faq)

Also I ended up modifying tf.cmd according to this. Seems to work so I'm going to let it be.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-intellij/issues/45

> This was due to the heap memory. By default there in the tf.cmd you are starting the tool by requesting a heap of 2048MB. This is too much for certain machine (as in my case). I changed the -Xmx param to 512 and now is all working fine.