# Adding a new Android project in empty TFS repo

Tags: android, tfs

I have a project on TFS with structure as follows:
[image: TFS image]

I have cloned it in Android studio like below:
[image: Android studio project]

Now I am unable to add a new Andorid project in AndroidApp repo. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first install [the VSTS plugin for IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-intellij-plug-in?view=vsts). This plugin is compatible with Android studio.

Suggest you to use **GIT** as your version control. Then it's not hard to create the repo and add/import code to your repo with git command line.

Detail tutorial please refer this link： **[VSTS Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/create-repo-intellij?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fjava%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fvsts%2Fjava%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts)**

---

If you want to use **TFVC** as your version control, you need to use the **TEE CLC** to provide the TFVC support.

For a Video tutorial, you could refer this link [Getting Started with TFVC inside of Android Studio with the Team Services Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8) You could also take a look at my reply in  [How to Use TFS in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531024/how-to-use-tfs-in-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

I ve generated from tfs web console . Get the git link . In android studio I already have my project . I ve used git command lines to add it . Also you have to install tfs plugin . 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/