# how to create repository or push code into subfolder over VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, android-studio-3.0

i am trying to push new project from android studio to VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service ).  I have used `Team Services Git` to import the existing project on VSTS.

[image]

now the problem is i really don't know how can i push my code into specific directory over VSTS shown in screenshot below.

[image]

whenever i click on `import into Team Services Git` it shows the dialog to enter my windows credential and after logging in successfully , i can just see the parent folder but not the child folder.

[image]

Comment: What's the version control system do you want to use, Git or TFVC? Based on the VSTS web page screen shot, it's a TFVC repo. Do you want to import the project into an existing repo or a new repo?

Comment: New repo and version is 2017

Comment: Want to use TFVC

Comment: If you're using TFVC, why would you choose the "Create Git repo" option and expect it to work?

Comment: true , but how should i create that TFVC too ?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT i have installed TFVC plugin and later on traverse through the required directory -> then created project into that directory in local  -> import code

Comment: @Hunt Unlike Git, you should not import code in VCS, in the version control bar, there should be a local changes option, select the folder and files, right click and choose commit changes, finally **check in** the changes. Then your local project should be sync synchronized to VSTS server side. **Precondition**: you have the correct workspace mapping for local `Andriod` folder. Suggest you take a look at the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8  (from 10:00~ 12:00) About the screenshot, please see my update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update:***

Unlike Git, you should not import code in VCS.

In the version control bar, there should be a local changes option, select the folder and files, right click and choose commit changes, finally **check in** the changes. Then your local project should be sync synchronized to VSTS server side. **Precondition**: you have the correct workspace mapping for local `Andriod` folder.

[image]

---

You need first install [the VSTS plugin for IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-intellij-plug-in?view=vsts). This plugin is compatible with Android studio.

You could  use **GIT** as your version control. Then it's not hard to create the repo and add/import code to your repo with git command line.

Detail tutorial please refer this link： **[VSTS Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/create-repo-intellij?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fjava%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fvsts%2Fjava%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts)**

---

According to the comment, seems you want to use **TFVC** as your version control, you have to use the **TEE CLC** to provide the TFVC support.

For a Video tutorial, you could refer this link [Getting Started with TFVC inside of Android Studio with the Team Services Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8) You could also take a look at my reply in  [How to Use TFS in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531024/how-to-use-tfs-in-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)