# how to add solution to TFVC on android Studio directly?

Tags: android, tfs, tfvc

I created a project on android studio and install and configured a TFS.

I don't want to add my project to TFS and then on my android studio open it as new from source control.

on my cause android studio and TFS both have been configured and everything is ok but I don't know is it possible to add my project to TFS in Android Studio or not? because when I right click on my solution and select TFVC as you can see on my photo "Add" option is disable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to add local code/project/solution in android studio to TFS as TFVC version control.

In the version control bar, there should be a local changes option, select the folder and files, right click and choose commit changes, finally **check in** the changes. Then your local project should be sync synchronized to TFS server side.

[image]

**Precondition**: you have the correct workspace mapping for local `Andriod` folder.  Besides to use **TFVC** as your version control, you have to use the **TEE CLC** to provide the TFVC support.

For a Video tutorial, you could refer this link [Getting Started with TFVC inside of Android Studio with the Team Services Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8) Suggest you to refer from (10:00~ 12:00) which talk about related things.

You could also take a look at my reply in  [How to Use TFS in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531024/how-to-use-tfs-in-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)